# Byte is decreased after mongo copy to another server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I am a newbie to MongoDB.

I use mongodb [db.copyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/) command for copying database to another server.

After I copy(I got the Ok sign from mongo shell), I found something strange.

In my source Server db

```
> show dbs
newstrust             13.947GB
```

In my Target Server db

```
> show dbs
ntrust1     2.188GB
```

I checked my db and compare source server db and target server db. The number of collections and rows are same.

I am not able to understand the problem

Comment: Have you deleted lots of information (in some point) from newstrust? Because a copy of the database will "remove" all empty space.

Comment: Thank's JJussi! I got hint of my question from your answer. I write my understanding in new answer. Really, really thanks. you save my day